# How to get pulse sound level

Tags: scripts, pulseaudio

I'm using simple keyboard shortcuts to adjust sound level on my fluxbox

```
123 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 5+
122 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 5-
```

However I'd like to add some notification (notify-send) of actual sound level. Can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
notify-send "$(amixer -D pulse get Master | awk '$2== "Left:" {print $5}')"
```

Thanks!